# Gradle dependency declared (JSR310), but LocalDateTimeDeserializer not importable

Tags: java, json, eclipse, gradle

Scenario is:

- Gradle project
- **`@JsonProperty`**, cannot deserialize String into **`LocalDateTime`**
- Found this: http://andreitsibets.blogspot.com.br/2014/04/java8-localdate-jackson-json.html
- Ported that from **Maven** to **Grade**, of course
- I'm attempting to use **`@JsonDeserialize(using=LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)`**

**The problem:** I cannot import **`LocalDateTimeDeserializer`** into my code

Here is my gradle dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
   compile ("org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:$springSocialVersion")
   compile ("org.springframework.social:spring-social-config:$springSocialVersion")
   compile ("org.springframework.social:spring-social-security:$springSocialVersion", optional)
   compile ("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jacksonVersion")
   compile ("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonVersion")
   compile ("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$jacksonVersion")
   compile ("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:$jsr310Version")
   compile ("org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:$springSecurityCryptoVersion")
   compile ("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$servletApiVersion", provided)
   testCompile ("org.springframework:spring-test:$springVersion")
}
```

**I'm sure that it's a catch! Where is it?**

Thanks very much in advance for the help!

Comment: Which $jsr310Version are you using? I guess you are running java 8? And what exact error do you get when you try to import the deserializer?

Comment: Hey, @fateddy, version: 2.5.1, and yes: Java 8. I thought it had something to do with the class path, but can't guess, I'm very new to gradle.

Comment: `$jacksonVersion` and `$jsr310Version` should be the same. Using that exact dependencies definitely should work. If you don't see the dependencies within your IDE it might be that eclipse is unable to see the gradle-managed dependencies. I assume that you use the eclipse gradle plugin (Eclipse Integration Gradle, https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/) - make sure that "dependency management" is enabled for your project - then try and refresh the dependencies (can be found in the Gradle Context Menu, by right-clicking on the project root folder).

Comment: It wasn't the answer, but did help me! I didn't know that the versions of hte jsr310 and of jackson would follow each other. So I updated jackson to be at 2.5.1. But what did the trick was something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to import classes from dependencies in your project it might be that eclipse is unable to see the gradle-managed dependencies.

For better integration of gradle based project use the `Eclipse Integration Gradle` Plugin (https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle, look at the README.md for installation instructions).

To "convert" a project to a gradle-project:

- remove the current project (but do not delete the sources)
- import the project as `Gradle Project`

Now to update your project dependecies right-click on the project directory and run `Gradle` -> `Refresh Dependencies`

Answer (score 3):

OK, Solved!

The problem was (apparently) related to the class path.
I'm new to Eclipse development, so it's getting clearer and clearer for me each day how it works.

To solve similar problems, do the following:

1. Add the dependency to your gradle build
   **`compile ("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.5.1")`**
2. You have to refresh your class path. With gradle, to do that, run **`gradle cleanEclipse && gradle eclipse`**
3. Refresh your eclipse. On mine, I really had to restart it.

After this, it did the magic: the **`LocalDateTimeDeserializer`** was there for me to import.

**Note:** I don't like my own approach here *and* I believe that it was too cranky to be correct, so I will leave this question open in case anybody with a clearer understanding of what happened here gets a better answer.

Should serve as reference for those banging head like I were to move on.

Comment: Just look at my previous comment again. Every time you run `gradle cleanEclipse` you wipe out the project description file. To make better use of gradle use the `eclipse gradle plugin` which can be found at https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle (look at the README.md for installation instructions). Then remove the project from the workspace (but leave the sources) - then reimport the project again - but this time as `Gradle Project`. Now to update your project dependecies right click on the project directory and run `Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies`.

Comment: Hey, @fateddy. I might have not seen your last comment and replied it. That was the answer in the end. Please add me an answer here so I can voteup and check! You were correct in your comment.